# How to apply matrix to customimageview in viewpager?

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, android-viewpager

I have added custom imageview to viewpager, while setting matrix to canvas of customimageview , the customimageview doesn't drag with viepager movement
(like it is fixed in the  same place). I couldn't realize what the problem.

//this is my simeple ImagePagerAdapter of viewpager

public class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

```
private TabPageIndicator indicator;
private final int mSize;
private PageFragment pageFragment;
public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int size) {
    super(fm);
    mSize = size;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mSize;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    PageMatrixFragment fragment = new PageMatrixFragment(position);
    return  fragment;
}
```

}

public class PageMatrixFragment extends Fragment {

```
int pos;

public PageMatrixFragment(int pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CustomImageView customImageView = new CustomImageView(getActivity());
    if (pos % 2==0) {
        customImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }else{
        customImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    return customImageView;
}
```

}

public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

```
private Bitmap mMarker;
public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}
private void init() {
    mMarker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    float[] values =
            {1, 0, 50,
             0,   1,  50,
             0,  0, 1};
    matrix.setValues(values);
```

//problems  accure when I use this line it forces the movement of customimageview with viewpager
        c.setMatrix(matrix); 
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        c.drawBitmap(mMarker, 200, 200, paint);
    }
}

The first screenshot shows the start state ,
when I commented   matrix.setValues(values); line it works as should work like in 2_nd  screenshot
while I need to apply matrix to canvas ,but it causes the result like it is in 3_rd screenshot ,it doesn't move with viewpager/
[image]

Comment: Nobody knows the root of your problem, unless you post your code

Comment: I have edited my question,please review.

Comment: You don't need to extend ImageView,  just call setImageMatrix() and use scaleType="matrix"

Comment: I really need to extend imageview or view(in another case),as I need to add some custom animations and... ,in such case what could be the solution?